# How to use bower cli config (--config)

Tags: command-line-interface, config, bower

Looking at the configuration docs and at the source code of bower it appears that it is now possible to configure bower from the cli via `--config.proxy="http://something:1234/"`.

- Docs: https://bower.io/docs/config/#placement--order
- Source: https://github.com/bower/bower/blob/cea728c7bc44c103e411855a5f911bc34be402fd/packages/bower-config/lib/util/rc.js#L18-L21

Unfortunately, the docs are pretty poor and I am having issues getting it to actually work.

I am not familiar enough with Bower's internals to understand the source code, so I have been unable to determine if this would write to `.bowerrc`, even if I could get it to work.

Can anybody advise how to use the command and if it would write to `.bowerrc` or not?

Comment: did you ever figure this one out? same question!

Comment: Sadly not. I have pretty much given up on Bower now too. NPM can do everything that Bower could.